# Regex to match tags with <%= %>

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
/<([a-z]+)([^<]*)(style|Style)="([^"]*)"([^<]*)>/g
```

that matches any HTML tag with the `style` attribute and it works.

I added the `[^<]` to match only the current open tag.

But I also need to match tags with the `<%=` and `%>` characters, like:

```
<a href="<%= url %>" style="color:#000">Link</a>
```

How can I do?

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML, use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Thanks but I absolutely need regex in this case.

Comment: OK can you show some sample input and what do you mean by matching only the current open tag, shouldn't you look for `[>]*` instead of `[<]*` ?

Comment: I also have a comment regarding the regexp regarding the `style|Style` part. Change it to just `style` in lower case and add the `i` flag after the `g` flag, to ignore case when matching

Comment: If I don't put the [^<] (or [^>] as you said) it matches all the tags on the page. I need to parse all the single tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird html tag if you ask me, but that should do it I think:

```
/<([a-z]+)((?:[^<]|<%)*)(style)="([^"]*)"([^<]*)>/gi
                  ^^^
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/uD4dQ5)

`[^<]*` was replaced by `(?:[^<]|<%)*` which accepts either a non `<` character or `<%`.